# Shop Cart using &_SEESION and multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, html

i am making a shop cart using `$_SESSION`, my problem is the first data in the array is being overwritten by the new one can you help me with this?

here's my code:

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cart']= array();
    if(isset($_POST['addtocart'])){
                $newproduct= array(
                'code' => $_SESSION['code'],
                'color' => $_POST['color'],
                'size' =>$_POST['size'],
                'quantity' => 1);
                $_SESSION['cart'][]= $newproduct;

    }
```

Retrieving the values:

```
session_start();
foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] AS $item ) 
{  
echo 'code: ' . $item['code'] . '<br />'; 
echo 'color: ' . $item['color'];  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redeclare the cart session variable eah time

```
$_SESSION['cart']= array();
```

perhaps you should try:

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) ) $_SESSION['cart']= array();
```

ie:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) ) $_SESSION['cart']= array();

    if( isset( $_POST['addtocart'], $_POST['color'],$_POST['size'],$_SESSION['code'] ) ){
        $newproduct=array(
            'code'      =>  $_SESSION['code'],
            'color'     =>  $_POST['color'],
            'size'      =>  $_POST['size'],
            'quantity'  =>  1
        );
        $_SESSION['cart'][]= $newproduct;
    }

?>
```

Comment: where should i put this line below if(isset($_POST['addtocart']?

Comment: Replace the existing line `$_SESSION['cart']= array();` below `session_start()` with the second line. The problem is that every time the page loads the session variable `cart` is redeclared as an empty array

Comment: it works but i loops 4 times even thoug i only add to products

Comment: i only add 2 producrs but the outpout is 4

Comment: how would i check if the code has already in the array and if it is i will just update it

Comment: `if( in_array( $_SESSION['cart'],$newproduct ) )` etc probably

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105474/discussion-between-anecito-alima-santillan-and-ramraider).